# Referencing index of List -1

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Why does this not print the last element in the list.

```
>>> a_lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> print a_lst[-1]
6
>>> print a_lst[0:-1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I can see that if I just do a_lst[-1] it returns the expected last element.  But when I try to use it in a range [0:-1] it actually returns the penultimate element?

Comment: `a_lst[0:6]` / `a_lst[0:]` / `a_lst[0:None]` / `a_lst[:]` / ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a_lst[0:-1]` it is up to and NOT including the last element, `a_lst[-1]` is just the last element.

`a_lst[0:]` would get all the elements.

When you slice a list it  goes `a_list[start:stop-1:step]`, where the step is optional

```
In [32]: l[0:-1]
Out[32]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # all but last element

In [33]: l[0::2]  # start at first and step of 2
Out[33]: [1, 3, 5]

In [34]: l[0::3]  # start at first and step of 3
Out[34]: [1, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you Padraic, for taking the time to answer, and help me out.  I really appreciate it.  Sorry to everyone else who down voted my question.  I searched, but apparently not hard enough.  Apoplogies.